# How to show Single Place on Map

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am using this tutorial to build Location Based App:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

still i have a button by using that button i am *able to view all the nearest places on map*.

Here i *need one small change*, i also *want to show single place on map*, not all, only selected one....

Therefore, **in SinglePlace.xml**, i have given *an image button to view location for that particular place*....

Still i am using below *java class to get all*, please tell me what are the changes i need to do in my code **to get only single place** [which place i have selected]

```
      public class PlacesMapActivity extends MapActivity {
// Nearest places
PlacesList nearPlaces;

// Map view
MapView mapView;

// Map overlay items
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;

GeoPoint geoPoint;
// Map controllers
MapController mc;

double latitude;
double longitude;
OverlayItem overlayitem;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_places);

    // Getting intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Users current geo location
    String user_latitude = i.getStringExtra("user_latitude");
    String user_longitude = i.getStringExtra("user_longitude");

    // Nearplaces list
    nearPlaces = (PlacesList) i.getSerializableExtra("near_places");

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    // Geopoint to place on map
    geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(user_latitude) * 1E6),
            (int) (Double.parseDouble(user_longitude) * 1E6));

    // Drawable marker icon
    Drawable drawable_user = this.getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);

    itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable_user, this);

    // Map overlay item
    overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Your Location",
            "That is you!");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
    itemizedOverlay.populateNow();

    // Drawable marker icon
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_blue);

    itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

    mc = mapView.getController();

    // These values are used to get map boundary area
    // The area where you can see all the markers on screen
    int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minLong = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int maxLong = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    // check for null in case it is null
    if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
        // loop through all the places
        for (Place place : nearPlaces.results) {
            latitude = place.geometry.location.lat; // latitude
            longitude = place.geometry.location.lng; // longitude

            // Geopoint to place on map
            geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),
                    (int) (longitude * 1E6));

            // Map overlay item
            overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, place.name,
                    place.vicinity);

            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);


            // calculating map boundary area
            minLat  = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), minLat );
            minLong = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), minLong);
            maxLat  = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), maxLat );
            maxLong = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), maxLong );
        }
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

        // showing all overlay items
        itemizedOverlay.populateNow();
    }

    // Adjusting the zoom level so that you can see all the markers on map
    mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(Math.abs( minLat - maxLat ), Math.abs( minLong - maxLong ));

    // Showing the center of the map
    mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat)/2, (maxLong + minLong)/2 ));
    mapView.postInvalidate();

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

   }
```

Comment: Remove the loop that says `For(Place : nearbyPlaces.results) {` and replace with an assignment of `place` to the one you want.

Comment: @Floris this is the big question for me how can i assign that place, like we don't know which place user going to see....any code i need to replace...

Comment: Ah - your question is not "how do I show" but "how do I know what place the user selected". What does the user see before selecting, and how does he make a selection?

Comment: Do you have multiple buttons - one for each location the user might choose? Can you show an example of the code you use for your button? I tried following the link to your tutorial but got a blank page (just the title...).  Maybe you can edit your question...

Comment: @Cthulhu - I believe Mr.Ravi is the author of androidhive.info - the link provided in the OP.